# IOS Parse how do I retrieving objects from a query based on two classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I have two classes `User` and `Post`. The `User` class has a `userType` field and I want to retrieve all of the posts from a given `userType` lets call them group x. In the `Post` class I have a pointer to the `User` class.

I was trying to do something like, first retrieve all user Ids for the type of user I want:

```
PFQuery *queryUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kFTUserClassKey];
[queryUser whereKey:kFTUserTypeKey equalTo:kFTUserTypeX];
[queryUser whereKey:kFTUserLocationKey nearGeoPoint:nearGeoPoint withinMiles:miles];
[queryUser findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *usersTypeX, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSMutableArray *objectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                // Add ambassador ids into query
                for (PFObject *userX in usersTypeX) {
                    [objectIds addObject:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:kFTUserClassName objectId: userX.objectId]];
                }
            }
}];
```

And then I wanted to query based on these objectIds but I am not sure how to query on this array or if this is even the correct way to do this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse provides a `matchesQuery` method on query, so ...

```
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"userType" equalTo:@"X"];  // fix with your real user type
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[query whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
    // posts are posts where post.user.userType == X
}];
```